# Water Solenoid Valve 12 DC vs 220 AC

Tags: ac, dc, electromagnetism, solenoid, solenoid-valve

I want to buy some solenoid valves for watering system and attach it to Raspberry. I have choice of Solenoid valve with 12DC and 220AC. Is there any difference between them? I mean, maybe 220AC valve works more reliable?

Comment: Make sure you are using a solenoid valve designed for such applications.  Most of them have a very small, 12VDC or more commonly, 24VAC coil that operates a pilot valve that runs off of water pressure.  Those will be the most reliable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solenoids can be designed to work over a wide range of voltage and current.  One that works at 12 V DC is not inherently better or worse than one that runs on 220 V AC, assuming the mechanical parts are the same.

However, mixing water and high voltage is not a good idea safety-wise.  Assuming that the 12 V DC version doesn't require excessively thick wires, that would be what I'd favor.  Even better, run them from a separate completely isolated 12 V power supply.  That means any one connection to ground won't cause current to flow in unintended places.  It would take *two* faults for something bad to happen.